# QMetaType::Float not in QVariant::Type

Tags: c++, qt

I have got an application that is working fine but it wasn't compiled with the warnings turned on. I'm trying to turn it back on and sorting them out but running out of ideas on how to fix this. I have :

```
QVariant someVar     
QVariant::Type variantType = someVar.type();
switch (variantType) {
    case QMetaType::QString:
        doSomething1();
        break;
    case QMetaType::Float:
        doSomething2();
        break;
}
```

and got this warning/error:

```
error: case value ‘135’ not in enumerated type ‘QVariant::Type’ [-Werror=switch]
```

in the QMetaType::Float line. I checked up the QT docs and it listed QMetaType::Float as value 38. What could possibly have caused this?

The closest thing I can find is at https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/2510 which has the same error. Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Can you provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Qt plays somewhat dirty tricks witht these two enumerations (`QMetaType::Type` and `QVariant::Type`). Quoting 4.8.4 docs on `QVariant::type()`:

> Returns the storage type of the value stored in the variant. Although this function is declared as returning `QVariant::Type`, the return value should be interpreted as `QMetaType::Type`. In particular, `QVariant::UserType` is returned here only if the value is equal or greater than `QMetaType::User`.
>
> Note that return values in the ranges `QVariant::Char` through `QVariant::RegExp` and `QVariant::Font` through `QVariant::Transform` correspond to the values in the ranges `QMetaType::QChar` through `QMetaType::QRegExp` and `QMetaType::QFont` through `QMetaType::QQuaternion`.
>
> Also note that the types `void*`, `long`, `short`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned char`, `float`, `QObject*`, and `QWidget*` are represented in `QMetaType::Type` but not in `QVariant::Type`, and they can be returned by this function. However, they are considered to be user defined types when tested against `QVariant::Type`.

In other words, the function `QVariant::type()` returns values of `QMetaType::Type` typed as `QVariant::Type`, and those two enumerations share a lot (but not all) of their enumerators. This makes dealing with them in a strict type system difficult—they're basically wibbly-wobbly typey-wypey stuff.

In your case, notice that the enumerator `QMetaType::Float` is among those which do *not* have a direct equivalent in `QVariant::Type`.

I would say that the best way to silence the warning would be to change `variantType` to `QMetaType::Type`, potentially with a cast on initialisation and/or a comment referring to Qt docs if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Angew. I understands the problem now. I switched off this specific warnings to get things going. I'm wondering, is static_cast safe to use here? I doubt it is but I'm not exactly sure. reinterpret_cast as suggested by Kuba below doesn't work.

Comment: @Boon Yes, `static_cast` is safe here, and the proper way of treating one enumeration as another (when such need arises).

Answer (score 3):

Simply switch on the `QMetaType::Type`. It is valid to do so, since the meaning of `QVariant::type()` is that of `QMetaType::Type` in spite of the return type being `QVariant::Type`. It's an API quirk/bug that you have to work around:

```
QVariant variant = ...;
switch (static_cast<QMetaType::Type>(variant.type())) {
  ...
}
```

The reason for the quirk is entirely historic. `QVariant::type()` returns a "wrong" type, only to retain binary compatibility within the Qt 5 series. In Qt 6, IIRC the `QVariant::Type` is just an alias for `QMetaType::Type` (and probably a deprecated one, too).

Answer (score 1):

`QVariant::Type` does not contain an entry named `Float` (see [qvariant.h](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h#l130))